# Test simulating form input in React with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm testing out the form input of a React component with Jest but I'm having trouble finding the best way to select the form's input field for entry using React TestUtils. The documentation online shows an example using `refs`, but the React docs also state that `refs` should only be used on the parent and not the children of the component. Should I be attaching `refs` to each input field or is there a better way to traverse the DOM and select the particular element so I can simulate a click event on it?

This is my render

```
render (
    <form className="products">
      <input onChange={this.handleName} name="name" type="text" />
      <input onChange={this.hanndleAge} name="age" type="text" />
    </form>
)
```

and my test

```
it('Should parse input fields', () => {
   Product = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ProductComponent />);

   // This returns all the inputs but how do tell them apart? 
   let inputs = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(Product, 'input');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save refs if the only reason you want to use them is to be able to test your component.

`inputs` variable is a regular array with all the results, you can get to the desired result by index.

```
it('Should parse input fields', () => {
   Product = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ProductComponent />);

   // This returns all the inputs but how do tell them apart? 
   let inputs = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(Product, 'input');

   let firstInput = inputs[0];
   let secondInput = inputs[1];
});
```

You can also use regular browser API to traverse the DOM tree after you isolate the component's primary DOM element (in your case it's `form`):

```
it('Should parse input fields', () => {
   Product = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ProductComponent />);

   let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(Product);

   let firstInput = node.querySelector("[name=name]");
   let secondInput = node.querySelector("[name=age]");
});
```